# HTTP POST to a REST service that's secured by CAS using Mule

Tags: authentication, https, mule, cas, outbound

I'm attempting to POST an xml string to a REST service that's behind CAS using Mule 3.5.0 CE. I've configured the mule security manager and http security filter on the outbound endpoint but haven't had much success. The mule documentation hasn't been much help and I've come across a few posts on how to secure an inbound endpoint but nothing on authenticating an outbound request. Has anyone done this before and is it even possible? Thanks in advance.

```
<!-- CONNECTORS -->
<https:connector name="HttpsConnector">
    <service-overrides sessionHandler="org.mule.session.NullSessionHandler"/>
    <https:tls-server path="${truststore}" storePassword="password"/>
</https:connector>


<!-- ENDPOINTS -->
<https:endpoint name="PublishEndpoint" connector-ref="HttpsConnector"
    address="${my.url}" 
    method="POST" contentType="application/xml" exchange-pattern="request-response"
    keepAlive="true" />

<mule-ss:security-manager>
    <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider name="memory-provider" delegate-ref="authenticationManager" />
</mule-ss:security-manager>

<spring:beans>
    <ss:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <ss:authentication-provider>
            <ss:user-service id="userService">
                <ss:user name="${user}" password="${pwd}" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </ss:user-service>
        </ss:authentication-provider>
    </ss:authentication-manager>
</spring:beans>

<!-- publish xml string to service -->
<flow name="PublishFlow">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint ref="ReportEndpoint" />
    <https:outbound-endpoint ref="PublishEndpoint">
        <mule-ss:http-security-filter realm="mule-realm" securityProviders="memory-provider"/>
    </https:outbound-endpoint>
</flow>
```

Comment: `http-security-filter` is for inbound endpoints, not outbound ones. What kind of credentials does CAS expect? Just a user name and password in a Basic Auth authorization header? Something else?

Comment: @DavidDossot CAS first requires a username/password to start the authentication process. Then there's a few exchanges of tickets that happen to complete validation.

Comment: You can pass username/password in `https:outbound-endpoint` by using the eponymous attributes on it. But this won't do the "few exchanges of tickets".

Answer (score 0):

The CAS security scheme is not directly implemented by the HTTP requester which actually in 3.5.0 does only support non-preemptive BASIC authentication.

The best shot you have is to roll back to http:oubound endpoints and create a custom dispatcher to take care of the authentication by java code.